# Proof that if $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $C$ is a subset of $D$, then $A \setminus D$ is a subset of $B \setminus C$.

Tags: solution-verification

Started my proof by assuming that $A \subset B$ and $C \subset D$. Then I proceeded by supposing that $x \in  A \setminus D$. So $x \in  A$ and $x \notin D$. Is it valid to conclude that $x \notin C$ since  $C \subset D$? I'm assuming it is always true but I'm not sure if it is a valid argument I can use for formal proofs.

Aside from that, I'm also lost as to how I should continue my proof. For now I continued with my proof mentioned above and added "since $A \subset B$, then $x \in B$. Also, $x \notin C$ so it follows that $x \in B \setminus C$. Therefore,  $A \setminus D \subset B \setminus C$. " Although, I'm not really sure if this is a valid argument. For instance, I'm having doubts with $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$ since $x$ is also not an element of $D$. Therefore, there's a possibility that $x \in B \setminus D$ (??). Any help with regards as to how I should properly and formally prove this will be a great help.

**Edit**: Thanks a lot to everyone who verified my approach!

Comment: You can write $A\setminus D$ as `$A \setminus D$`

Comment: There is a possibility that $x \in B \setminus D$, because it's definitely true: you've proven both $x \in B$ (since $x \in A$) and $x \notin D$ (since $x \in A \setminus D$). That isn't a problem; it doesn't contradict what you want to show, which is $x \in A \setminus C$.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct stating that if $x\not\in D$, since $C\subset D$ then $x\not\in C$. If it isn't clear to you, look at the contraposition (if $x\in C$, since $C\subset D$ then $x\in D$).

In the second part, you proved that for every element $x\in A\setminus D$, you have $x\in B\setminus C$, therefore $A\setminus D\subset B\setminus C$. If $x\in B$ and $x$ is not an element of $D$ then automatically $x\in B\setminus D$.

Answer (score -1):

Your argument is right. In symbols, you're essentially doing $$A\subset B\quad\text{and}\quad D^c\subset C^c\implies A\cap D^c\subset B\cap C^c$$
using the fact that $M\subset N\iff N^c\subset M^c$, which is right.

Comment: You're downvoting and not explaining what did you disapprove. Kindly give me chance to improve, dear downvoter.

Comment: I think your explanation is too asbtract and doesn't seem to check OP's proof.